# String not printing properly using FprintF

Tags: go

I was trying my hand at an irc client but I can't get a string to "print" properly using Fprintf. This is the method that is not working:

```
func (irc *IrcConnection) sendMessage(message string, args ...interface{}) (error){

    fmt.Printf("Sending: "+message, args)
    _, err := fmt.Fprintf(irc.connection, message+" \r\n", args)
    if err != nil{
        return err;
    }

    return nil
}
```

An example of me calling it is

```
ircConnection.sendMessage("PASS %s",  ircConnection.info.password)
```

The output ends up being "PASS [password]", meaning that the password prints with square brackets instead of just the password.

I though at first it was the ...interface{} making it print like that but if I change it to ...string it has the same problem.

If I try:

```
var test interface{} = ircConnection.info.password
fmt.Printf("%s", test)
```

It prints without the brackets.

I'm pretty new to go and have no idea what to try next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just figured it out

```
 _, err := fmt.Fprintf(irc.connection, message+" \r\n", args)
```

needs to become

```
 _, err := fmt.Fprintf(irc.connection, message+" \r\n", args...)
```

I was trying to print an array/slice

Answer (score 1):

You want `fmt.Fprintf(irc.connection, message+" \r\n", args...`) — note the `args...`, not `args`. When your function declares `args ...interface{}` that means that it will get all of the remaining arguments as a slice. When you pass `args` to `Fprintf`, you're telling it to print that slice. As one thing, a slice. To flatten the slice back out into a list of arguments you use the `...`.

See [Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).